# SQLite primary key options

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios

I'm writing a mobile application that stores data in a SQLite database. The standard auto-increment id primary key column will be a pain when I'm trying to synchronise the device with a server database and other devices. Previously I've used GUID's for primary keys in SQLServerCE which is effective when transferring data from multiple mobile databases to a single server database. But GUIDs are not a supported datatype in SQLite. What is the best/simplest option for creating a *globally* unique id in SQLite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost every datatype (except for integer) will be stored as strings, So why don't you generate your guid in your app and store it in the primary key (string) column ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way IMHO, is passing a GUID from your code (obtained via Guid.NewGuid()) along with the rest record data on the record insert.